# Getters in Java for novice java users

Tags: java, getter-setter

Getters and setters are used to implement two of the fundamental aspects of Object Oriented Programming which are

```
Abstraction
Encapsulation
```

Suppose we have an Employee class:

```
package com.highmark.productConfig.types;

public class Employee {

private String firstName;
private String middleName;
private String lastName;

public void getFirstName(){
    return this.firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public void setMiddleName(String middleName) {
    this.middleName = middleName;
}

// Similarly for lastName

public String getFullName(){
    return this.getFirstName() + this.getMiddleName() + this.getLastName();
}
}
```

UPDATE : Is this usage right with the workerclass?

```
public class getNames() {

private String firstName;
private String middleName;
private String lastName;

//Constructor
    public String getNames() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner();
        // output message to insert name part
        String firstName = input.ReadLine();
        String middleName = input.ReadLine();
        String lastName = input.ReadLine();
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        emp.setFirstName(firstName);
        emp.setMiddleName(middleName);
        emp.setLastName(lastName);
    }
}
```

Please try to explain the flaw in understanding if any.

Comment: @Mohit can you elaborate more over here. Am just looking for some conceptual clearance. I think I am mistaken with the usage and so want to clear it.

Comment: is your getFirstName belong to Employee or some other class?

Comment: Perhaps @Tomaltach says it should not belong to the Employee Class. In my question it does belong to Employee class though.

Comment: Yes that would be the correct usage...Although it would be better to use a method called `GetEmployeeInfo()` rather than creating a class called `getNames()` as this would get confusing to other developers.

Comment: Better, but the method should probably return the constructed `Employee` object. And rather then making an empty employee, then setting it's properties via setters, that would better be done via a constructor.

Comment: @zapl  If this is the right usage then plese vote up the question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are correct on one thing for sure. **Getters are Setters** are a way to ensure the principle of **Encapsulation** in Object Oriented Programming languages like Java.

When you have a private member in your class, then **its scope gets restricted** to that particular class itself, but you may want to provide getters and/or setters to make that member accessible to classes outside your class.

Suppose you have a member like this,

```
private String firstName;
```

then this is your getter for this member,

```
public String getFullName(){
    return this.getFirstName() + this.getMiddleName() + this.getLastName();
}
```

but this is not,

```
public String getFirstName() {
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
    firstName = user_input.next( );         
    return firstName;
}
```

because **"getter"** is just a term used to get the value of a member which is private. *The sole purpose of a getter method is just to get the original value of a member.*

In the latter method, the purpose is absolutely different. You are trying to get the first name as input, so technically it cannot be called a "getter" in any way.

Hope this clears your doubt.

Comment: thanks for the info. But like previous user said i implemented a worker class. Is that right? And technically it still doesnt satisfy your definition of a getter. Help.

Comment: yes i realized what you are trying to say. Rather than making the private data values available, to display their value, we use the getter method to get(or display) the current value of the private global value.

Comment: Yes the worker class implementation is correct. And no, it will not be a getter. I would recommend you to go through my answer to clear your confusion.